# Select2 with Stimulus and webpacker in Rails 6

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs

I recently updated to rails 6 and using webpacker and stimulus.  It is making a lot of features a lot easier to work with turbolinks, but Im having trouble figuring out how to make some the select2 gem work with stimulus and webpacker and keep getting errors when i try to import it in my application.js file.  Looking for a point in the right direction to get select2 up and running.

Comment: Please provide more details about errors you've got

Comment: From the readme: "Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes"

Do you have jquery installed?

Comment: @eirvandelden yes i installed the jQuery but still not get it the bootstrap4 date picker

Answer (score 0):

It's funky, but this is what I had to do to get Select2 to work. I haven't been able to get the styling to match my normal selects, though.

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js

window.Rails = Rails # this line might not be needed
window.$ = $


# config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')


environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Rails: '@rails/ujs',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```